# CDN_SELCHANGE notification message generated by the FileOpenDialog work for 32bit build not for 64bit build

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit

I download "Extensible Dialogs Source"(**C# using P/Invoke**) from website which is written by Microsoft to show how to place Windows Forms controls inside one of the common file dialogs. (Like: add preview function).
This project has test client code, which is to open a dialog, once you click a picture, you can have a preview of the picture on the right side of the dialog.
Test client code works well in **32 bit build**, but doesn't work in **64 bit build**.

After some debugging, I found it is because in 64 bit build, CDN_SELCHANGE notification message from

```
    [DllImport("ComDlg32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool GetOpenFileName( ref OpenFileName ofn );
```

can not be recognized or not handled right in c# code.

```
// WM_NOTIFY - we're only interested in the CDN_SELCHANGE notification message
// we grab the currently-selected filename and fire our event
case WindowMessage.Notify:
{
    IntPtr ipNotify = new IntPtr( lParam );
    OfNotify ofNot = (OfNotify)Marshal.PtrToStructure( ipNotify, typeof(OfNotify) );
    UInt16 code = ofNot.hdr.code;
    if( code == CommonDlgNotification.SelChange )
    {
       // This is the first time we can rely on the presence of the content panel
       // Resize the content and user-supplied panels to fit nicely
       FindAndResizePanels( hWnd );

       // get the newly-selected path
       IntPtr hWndParent = NativeMethods.GetParent( hWnd );
       StringBuilder pathBuffer = new StringBuilder(_MAX_PATH);
       UInt32 ret = NativeMethods.SendMessage( hWndParent, CommonDlgMessage.GetFilePath, _MAX_PATH, pathBuffer );
       string path = pathBuffer.ToString();

       // copy the string into the path buffer
       UnicodeEncoding ue = new UnicodeEncoding();
       byte[] pathBytes = ue.GetBytes( path );
       Marshal.Copy( pathBytes, 0, _fileNameBuffer, pathBytes.Length );

       // fire selection-changed event
       if( SelectionChanged != null ) SelectionChanged( path );
     }
     return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Even I select different file in OpenFileDialog,`ofNot.hdr.code` is always 0, as a result, application never runs into code block after `if( code == CommonDlgNotification.SelChange )`.
Can anybody make this test sample work in 64 bit build? Thanks in advance!

Sample code download link: [ExtensibleDialogsSource.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/2/082d8e20-8376-4802-92a6-3a92552fea4a/ExtensibleDialogsSource.msi)

Comment: This is the wrong way to extend file dialogs. Use IFileDialogCustomize.

Comment: My crystal ball says that the OfNotify declaration is wrong.  NMHDR.idFrom is easy to fumble for example, should be IntPtr.  It is visible wrong for NMHDR.code, it is not UInt16.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all nice replies, I figured out the solution. Some **structs definition is wrong** when it applies to **64 bit application**.
In NativeMethods.cs (Written by Microsoft which may not target to **64 bit application**), it defines

```
/// <summary>
/// Part of the notification messages sent by the common dialogs
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct NMHDR
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]    public IntPtr   hWndFrom;
    [FieldOffset(4)]    public UInt16   idFrom;
    [FieldOffset(8)]    public UInt16   code;
};

/// <summary>
/// Part of the notification messages sent by the common dialogs
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct OfNotify
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]    public NMHDR    hdr;
    [FieldOffset(12)]   public IntPtr   ipOfn;
    [FieldOffset(16)]   public IntPtr   ipFile;
};
```

Since size of IntPtr is changed **from 4 bytes to 8 bytes.**
So we need to **redefine structs**.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct NMHDR
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr hWndFrom;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr idFrom;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public UInt16 code;
};

/// <summary>
/// Part of the notification messages sent by the common dialogs
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct OfNotify
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public NMHDR hdr;
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public IntPtr ipOfn;
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public IntPtr ipFile;
};
```

And now it works for 64 bit application.

From my point of view, we'd better use .Net lib if possible, which can make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

NMHDR idFrom is not IntPtr, but UINT in MSDN2005. Later it is documented as UINT_PTR...